# How to make a gender list for registration form

Tags: html, css, button, navbar, dropdown

I'm kind of improvising because I'm new to this, I've coded this registration form:[image]

But it needs the gender selection list that all websites have on there registration form. How can I do this? Also, is there a better way to code a date of birth menu? I don't really like the example I got from w3schools. I'll leave my code below:

HTML:

```
<nav>
      <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home">INICIO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">CONTACTO</li>
          <li class="with-arrow">REGISTRATE
            <div class="register-box">
              <h1 id="datos-registro">Ingresa tus datos</h1>
              <form>
                <p>¿Cómo te llamas?</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Tu nombre">
                <p>¿Cuál es tu apellido?</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Tu apellido">
                <p>¿Cuándo naciste?</p>
                <input type="date">
                <p>¿Cómo es tu correo?</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Tu e-mail">
                <p>Elige una buena contraseña</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Elige una contraseña">
                <p>Confirmala (¡por si acaso!)</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Confirmala">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo" >
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="with-arrow">INGRESAR
            <div class="login-box">
              <h2 id="datos-ingreso">Datos</h2>
              <form>

                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Escribir e-mail">

                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Escribir Contraseña">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Listo">
                <a href="">¿Contraseña olvidada?</a>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.register-box{
                width: 350px;
                height: 515px;
                padding: 80px 40px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                top: 100%;
                visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;
                cursor: auto;
            }
                .menu li .register-box {
              transform: translateX(25px) scale(.5);
              opacity: 0;
              transition: .15s all linear;


            }

            .menu li:hover .register-box {
              display: block;
              visibility: visible;
              opacity: 1;
              transform: translateX(0px);
              transition: .15s all linear;
            }

            h1{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 20px;
                color: #efed40;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 25px;

            }
            .register-box p{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: white;
            }
            .register-box{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: white;
            }
            .register-box{

                margin-bottom: 20px;

            }
            .register-box input[type="text"], input[type="password"]
            {
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                background: transparent;
                outline: none;
                height: 20px;
                color: white;
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            .register-box input[type="submit"]
            {
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                height: 40px;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 16px;
                background: #ff267e;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 20px;
                top: 0;
            }
            .register-box input[type="submit"]:hover
            {
                cursor: pointer;
                background: #efed40;
                color: #262626;


            }
            .register-box{
                text-align: center;
            }
            .register-box input
            {
                width: 80%;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .register-box input[type="date"]{
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                background: transparent;
                outline: none;
                height: 40px;
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
                font-size: 16px;
            }
            .register-box p
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: white;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<input type="date">` for the purpose of creating a date picker

```html
<input type="date">
```

use radio button for the gender part

```html
Gender <input type="radio" value="Male">Male <input type="radio" value="Female">Female
```